# How to display camera within a Form/Page?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, xamarin, camera

I'm currently working on what you could call a pet project, in which I need to display the camera. I've gotten that to work so far, but the idea behind it requires the view of the camera to not take up the entire screen. How can I "limit" or attach it to some other object/view that I can limit in size so as that I don't take up the entire screen, and thus I can add text/buttons/etc that the user can interact with while at the same time viewing the camera content?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use some different native APIs to get a view that can show the camera feed. This is a different approach from using something like the Media Plugin which shows the built-in platform cameras. For example, you would use `AVCaptureSession` for iOS. Luckily, we have a doc on doing just what you want [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/contentpage/). The example code is quite large so I won't paste here. There is a GitHub project you can explore for the full source code [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/ContentPage).

The basic idea is to create a renderer for the platform APIs that give you access to camera data that can be embedded in a view.

iOS:
`AVCaptureSession`, `AVCaptureDeviceInput` and `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`

Android:
`SurfaceTexture` and `TextureView` help